# Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file... in line

Tags: php, string, parameters, warnings

I have this error:

> Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /includes/functions/general.php on line 159

Line 159 is:

```
if ((strlen($value) > 0) && ($key != tep_session_name()) && ($key != 'error') && (!in_array($key, $exclude_array)) && ($key != 'x') && ($key != 'y')) {
```

Could you help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**[`strlen()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) only works for strings.** From the [**`strlen()` documentation**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#refsect1-function.strlen-notes):

> `strlen()` returns `NULL` when executed on arrays, and an `E_WARNING` level error is emitted.

---

If you have an array, use [**`count()`**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to count the elements:

```
if (count($value) > 0)
```